# c# MVVM restart and main menu button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my View folder I have MainWindow and GameWindow, in my ViewModel folder I have MainWindowViewModel and GameWindowViewModel. I'm trying from my GameWindowViewModel:

1) To restart my GameWindow on click with an ICommand and this function

```
void restartButtonClickFunction(object obj)
    {
        GameWindow gamewindow = new GameWindow();
        Application.Current.GameWindow.Close();
        gamewindow.Show();
    }
```

2) To go to my MainWindow again on click with an ICommand and the following function

```
void mainMenuButtonClickFunction(object obj)
    {
        MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.GameWindow.Close();
        mainwindow.Show();
    }
```

It gives me errors and I can't figure out an other way. In my MainWindowViewModel I managed with the following function

```
void startButtonClickFunction(object obj)
    {
        GameWindow gamewindow = new GameWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
        gamewindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'GameWindow' and no extension method 'GameWindow' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\...\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\...\...\viewmodel\gamewindowviewmodel.cs 907 33 Hangman

Comment: Ah yes, `Application.Current.MainWindow` isn't a reference to your `MainWindow` class. It's a property on `Application` that indiciates which window is the 'Main' one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx. Therefore, there isn't an `Application.Current.GameWindow`

Comment: You could use `Application.Current.Windows` to get a list of `Windows` and then select the one you want by comparing the `Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

`Application.Current.MainWindow` isn't a reference to your `MainWindow` class, it's a property on `Application` that indicates which `Window` is the 'Main' one, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx.

This means that there isn't a property `Application.Current.GameWindow`.

Instead you could use `Application.Current.Windows` to get a collection of all the current `Windows` and then compare the type to get the one you want to close:

```
foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is GameWindow)
    {
        ((Window)window).Close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could store the current `Window` in a property to allow you to easily close it

Answer (score 0):

it works for the MainMenu Button but when I try to restart the window with the following code the current Window closes but won't open again and gives the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

```
 void restartButtonClickFunction(object obj)
    {
        GameWindow gamewindow = new GameWindow();
        foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window is GameWindow)
            {
                ((Window)window).Close();
            }
        }
        gamewindow.Show();
    }
```